# why the server socket does not proceed?

Tags: java, sockets, stream

my app for college work..

DOC to PDF

==

my server:

**one thread per requisition**

```
        server = new ServerSocket(5000);

        while (true) {
            Socket cliente = server.accept();
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Requisitor(cliente));
            thread.start();
        }
```

my class Requisitor (run method)

```
@Override
public void run() {
    // receive doc binary
    receive();
    // doc to pdf
    Conversor converson = new Conversor(new File("docs/"+cliente.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()+".doc"),new File("pdfs/"+cliente.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()+".pdf"));
    converson.converter();
    //response pdf binary to client
    response();
}
```

but the method receive() is not called.. only when i disconect client socket.

my client socket:

```
    Client cliente = new Client();
    cliente.connect();
    cliente.send(); // send doc binary

    boolean flag = true;

    while (flag) {
        if(!cliente.streamIsEmpty()){ // wait for conversion
            cliente.receive(); // receive pdf
            flag = false;
        }
    }


    cliente.disconect()
```

my receive method

```
        InputStream in = cliente.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(in);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("docs/"+cliente.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()+".doc");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length = 0;

        while((length = stream.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        out.flush();
        stream.close();
```

any idea? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you read until -1 is returned by the stream read.  This happens when the socket is closed.  Try closing the OutputStream within cliente.send() (not the whole socket) after it writes the document.

```
    while((length = stream.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
```

Comment: +1 - If his client code didn't close its output stream, that would certainly explain the problem.

Comment: Also, I noticed that when waiting for the response, you.. cliente.streamIsEmpty()) { // wait for conversion cliente.receive() - this should be unnecessary. calling stream.read(buffer) will block until the server starts sending data.

Comment: Closing the output stream closes the socket too. There is no such thing as `clos[ing] the OutputStream ... (not the whole socket)`. Not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear.  It looks like you have two methods called receive (one in the client and one in the server).  You say that "the method receive() is not called"  but you don't say WHICH one is not being called.

But one thing that is definitely wrong is this:

```
boolean flag = true;
while (flag) {
    if (!cliente.streamIsEmpty()) { // wait for conversion
        cliente.receive(); // receive pdf
        flag = false;
    }
```

Your code is busy-waiting which is bad.  And besides, where is no need to wait like that.  Just call `cliente.receive()` ... which will block until something arrives ... or the server disconnects.